# Incluir um arquivo.c dentro de um projetoprincipal.c

Tags: c

Estou desenvolvendo um programa simples para entregar no fim do primeiro semestre e gostaria de saber se é possível criar um projeto principal e fazer o menu em um `menu.c` separado. Depois incluir o arquivo do `menu.c` dentro do projeto principal?

Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

  /* Esse é o projeto principal que esta salvo como projeto.c
     e queria incluir aqui o menu.c */


   return(0);
}
```

Daí quero salvar `menu.c` e incluir ele dentro do `projeto.c` acima.

Comment: Se adicionar mais detalhes do que está fazendo, eu melhoro a resposta. Como o que foi postado, não consigo responder mais que isto.

Comment: Tudo bem, já me ajudou bastante. Eu não fiz muita coisa ainda, mas o que estou pensando em fazer é um programa simples de RH, onde ele guarde todas as informações dos funcionários e etc. O que eu queria fazer é um arquivoprincipal.c , um menu.c e um loginsenha.c para separar tudo e tentar talvez deixar mais organizado...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para fazer o que deseja basta colocar um `#include "menu.c"` no local onde quer incluir, mas eu duvido que é isto que realmente precisa.

A solução correta é compilar os dois arquivos, um chamado as funções do outro. Isto pode ser feito na linha de comando ou adicionando todos os arquivos no projeto gerenciado pelo IDE.

Comment: Obrigada, sobre a sua resposta encontrei um link aqui que talvez possa ajudar mais pessoas diante do raciocínio que me passou. Segue o link: http://www.hardware.com.br/comunidade/arquivo-funcao/988264/